# Passing File Data from Parent Flow to Child Flow

Tags: sharepoint, parent-child, power-automate

I am struggling with passing file data from a Parent Flow to a Child Flow.

In the parent flow, I use SharePoint Get Items to pull a list containing the individual SharePoint sites within our domain.  At the moment, this is running about 230 individual sites.  Using Apply to Each, I peruse through the sites using Get Files (properties only) to locate any files created in the last 20 minutes. If there are files created, I again use the Apply to Each, and pass the information to my Child Flow.

The child flow is pretty simple.  It responds to the parent; SharePoint Copy File to a new location in SharePoint; Logs the entry into an excel table; then sends an email.

Copies of the flow are below.  HOWEVER, here is the challenge. I can not figure out how to identify the file that needs to be passed into the Child.   I have played with this for hours.

[image: Detail of teh Child Flow Atributes]

I beleive the challenge is, I am unable to select the File Identifier from the Get Files Properties Only step in my Dynamic Content Menu...only from the orginal Get Items step.  But I might be wrong.  Not finding much in my research.

Here is the Detailed View of the Parent Flow

[image: Detailed Parent Flow (Part 1)]

[image: Detailed Parent Flow (Part 2)]

Here is the Detailed view of my Child Flow

[image: Detailed Child Flow]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the File Identifier is just used to identify the specific file, which is always a necessary parameter in the flow with "*". In the child flow, there are "SharePoint Site", "Hotel" and "Acctfile" to specific which file to use. So there is no need to fill File Identifier in "File Content Name".

What's more, the type of File Identifier data may not match what it should be in "File Content Name".

You could also check what is wrong with this flow from the flow error details.

Comment: Those other parameters are used to identify the file path to copy the file to, but not the file that needs to be copied.  The file that needs to be copied comes from the Get File (Properties Only) portion of the parent flow......but I can not get the file identifier option from that part of the flow (only the identifier from the Get Items part of the flow.)